# Rails redirect_to does not work when using Turbolinks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, turbolinks

My application is using Rails 5 and when I include `turbolinks` in `application.js`:

```
//= require turbolinks
```

It works when I use `redirect_to` in the controller:

```
redirect_to "/manage-content"
```

But when I remove `turbolinks`, `redirect_to` does not work any more.

What can I do to fix this? Is it possible to use `redirect_to` without `turbolinks`?

Comment: Are you sure the controller action redirecting to "/manage-content" is indeed hit ? The problem could occur in your view instead.